# Why does this flashlight lens have this shape?

Tags: optics

I pulled apart a flashlight and found a similar lens as the one shown below.

[image]

I assume that the light starts off as a “point source” somewhere inside and the curvature and/or shape of the “lens” makes parallel wavefronts (or rays) exit the flashlight in a somewhat collimated beam. Is this approximating correct? Almost all of the websites really didn’t give any detailed information or was unclear that I found. I would love for someone to explain this in more detail if possible.

Comment: What flashlight is this from? What websites did you visit? Where is the bulb situated?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus: Sorry but I don't know the name of the flashlight but the image of the lens is from the following website: http://dx.com/p/21mm-led-acrylic-lens-for-flashlight-5-pack-41690. As I stated above, I took apart a flashlight and found a similar lens of this shape inside. The light was located at the base (bottom of the image) of this lens.

Comment: The shape is a paraboloid of rotation and the point is to focus the light over a wider angular range than a spherical reflector would manage. The key word to search is "[spherical aberration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_aberration)".

Comment: @dmckee: thanks for the link. I found a link from the page you suggested that makes me think the lens is a aspheric lens (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspheric_lens).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The reflector focuses the light from the bulb which is a point source to a straight line.

Comment: where did you get this image? I was hoping to find something like this on the web but couldn't. This is exactly what I expected but was unsure of myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The lens on the image is known as a Total Internal Reflection (**TIR**) lens. The benefit of this type of lens is to achieve a more controlled and uniform beam of light by principle of total internal reflection. For example in flashlights.

More information here: https://www.ledil.com/support/guide-to-tir-lenses/ and here https://www.opticsforhire.com/blog/what-is-a-tir-lens

**NB** - I'm not involved with LEDIL or Opticsforhire in any way, they simply have decent articles explaning the TIR lens.